(autonomous driving) Does BeamNG.tech/Py have usable Outputs for Collision detection, crossing of lanes, traffic signs...?
I want to train an AI for autonomous driving using reinforcement learning that you can potentially race against while paying attention to good driving and following traffic rules.
I am looking at 2 different tools (Carla and BeamNG). Carla gives a lot of Outputs regarding your driving (like collision detection, crossing lanes, ...) and while looking at the BeamNG.py documentation I only found something regarding the aggressiveness of your driving but nothing regarding Collision or traffic signs and stuff like that.
Does BeamNG.PY API offer something for that?
I appreciate all answers and have a great day!
I checked the docu and didn't find anything in the examples

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If BeamNG.py gives feedback regarding collision that can be used as input for a ai-model
